# Why can't "chgport.exe" be found by Runtime.getRuntime().exec() in Java?

Tags: java, windows

In Java, I've tried to run:
`Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Windows\\System32\\chgport.exe");`
as well as
`Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chgport.exe");`

but getting the following Exception:

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Windows\System32\chgport.exe": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

I am using the NetBeans IDE and it is running with admin credentials.

Comment: According to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String), exec doesn't require an absolute/relative path, but a command

Comment: @dnsiv I've also tried without using a path, but get the same error.

Comment: Did you try something like this yet? `String[] cmdArray = new String[]{"C:\Windows\System32\chgport.exe"}; Runtime.exec(cmdArray);`

Comment: @dnsiv Yes. Using "mspaint.exe" works fine. change to "chgport.exe", and "chgport.exe" just cannot be found. My IDE runs as admin and "chgport.exe" is executable by user anyway. There is "something" about the "chgport.exe" file (and it doesn't seem to be permissions).

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code and its working fine, Try it like so:

```
String[] command = {"chgport"};
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
pb.directory(new File("C:/Windows/System32/"));
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process p = pb.start();
```

I tried both methods from Eclipse and both are working fine
Is it possible that you are not running your IDE with Administrator rights?
Can you try close the IDE and right click run as administrator?

```
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Windows\\System32\\mspaint.exe");
        p.waitFor();

        String[] command = {"mspaint"};
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
        pb.directory(new File("C:/Windows/System32/"));
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process p2 = pb.start();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: "mspaint.exe" is a great example that will help me figure this out, but I haven't yet. My IDE runs as admin and "chgport" is executable by user anyway, so I don't know. This is very strange.

Answer (score 0):

You could run it with `CMD /C`, which "carries out the command specified by string and then terminates".

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("CMD /C chgport.exe");
```